# How to find word frequency in a text file?

Tags: java, word-frequency

My task is to get the word frequency of this file:

**test_words_file-1.txt**:

```
The quick brown fox
Hopefully245this---is   a quick13947
task&&#%*for you to complete.
But maybe the tASk 098234 will be less
..quicK.
the the the the the the the the the the
```

I've been trying to remove symbols and digits from this file and get each word's frequency in alphabetical order, and the result is:

[image: word list]

I can see that even digits have been removed but are still being counted. Can you explain why and how can I fix this?

Also, how can I separate *"Hopefully245this---is"* and store 3 useful words *"hopefully", "this", "is"*?

```java
public class WordFreq2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Downloads\\test_words_file-1.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); 
        int maxWordLen = 0; 
        String maxWord = null;

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            // text cleaning 
            word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");

            if(map.containsKey(word)) {
                //if the word already exists
                int count = map.get(word)+1;
                map.put(word,count);
            }
            else {
                // The word is new 
                int count = 1;
                map.put(word, count);

                // Find the max length of Word
                if (word.length() > maxWordLen) {
                    maxWordLen = word.length();
                    maxWord = word;
                }
            }   
        }

        scanner.close();

        //HashMap unsorted, sort 
        TreeMap<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<>();
        sorted.putAll(map);


        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: sorted.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }

        System.out.println(maxWordLen+" ("+maxWord+")");
    }

}
```

Comment: `String[] tokens = text.split("[\\s\\d]+");`?

Answer (score 2):

First the code. The explanation appears after the below code.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordFreq2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Downloads\\test_words_file-1.txt");
        try {
            String text = Files.readString(path); // throws java.io.IOException
            text = text.toLowerCase();
            Pattern pttrn = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
            Matcher mtchr = pttrn.matcher(text);
            TreeMap<String, Integer> freq = new TreeMap<>();
            int longest = 0;
            while (mtchr.find()) {
                String word = mtchr.group();
                int letters = word.length();
                if (letters > longest) {
                    longest = letters;
                }
                if (freq.containsKey(word)) { 
                    freq.computeIfPresent(word, (w, c) -> Integer.valueOf(c.intValue() + 1));
                }
                else {
                    freq.computeIfAbsent(word, (w) -> Integer.valueOf(1));
                }
            }
            String format = "%-" + longest + "s = %2d%n";
            freq.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf(format, k, v));
            System.out.println("Longest = " + longest);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Since your sample file is small, I load the entire file contents into a `String`.

Then I convert the entire `String` to lower-case since your definition of a word is a series of consecutive alphabetic, case-insensitive characters.

The regular expression – `[a-z]+` – searches for one or more consecutive, lower-case, alphabetic characters. (Remember the entire `String` is now all lower-case.)

Each successive call to method `find()` will find the next word in the `String` (according to the above definition of a word, i.e. a consecutive series of lower-case letters of the alphabet).

To count the letter frequencies, I use a `TreeMap` where the map key is the word and the map value is the number of times that word appears in the `String`. Note that map keys and values cannot be primitives, hence the value is `Integer` and not `int`.

If the last word found already appears in the map, I increment the count.

If the last word found does not appear in the map, it is added to the map and its count is set to 1 (one).

Along with adding the words to the map, I count the letters of each word found in order to find the longest word.

After the entire `String` is processed, I print the contents of the map, one entry per line, and finally print the number of letters in the longest word found. Note that `TreeMap` sorts its keys, hence the list of words appears in alphabetical order.

Here is the output:

```
a         =  1
be        =  1
brown     =  1
but       =  1
complete  =  1
for       =  1
fox       =  1
hopefully =  1
is        =  1
less      =  1
maybe     =  1
quick     =  3
task      =  2
the       = 12
this      =  1
to        =  1
will      =  1
you       =  1
Longest = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

> And how can I separate "Hopefully245this---is" and store 3 useful
>   words "hopefully", "this", "is"?

Use regex API for such a requirement.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hopefully245this---is";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hopefully
this
is
```

Check the following links to learn more about Java regex:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
3. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Answer (score 0):

On Java 9 or newer [Matcher#results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) could be used in a stream solution like this:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Downloads\\test_words_file-1.txt"))) {
        br.lines()
                .map(pattern::matcher)
                .flatMap(Matcher::results)
                .map(matchResult -> matchResult.group(0))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
                .forEach((word, count) -> System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", word, count));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
    }
```

Output:

```
a=1
be=1
brown=1
but=1
complete=1
for=1
fox=1
hopefully=1
is=1
less=1
maybe=1
quick=3
task=2
the=12
this=1
to=1
will=1
you=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Nandini\\Downloads\\CountFreq.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
    while( s.hasNext() )
    {
             String word = s.next();
             word = word.toLowerCase();
            if( !counts.containsKey( word ) )
             counts.put( word, 1 );
            else
             counts.put( word, counts.get(word) + 1 );
    }
    System.out.println(counts);
  }
  
}
```

**Output:**
{the=1, this=3, have=1, is=2, word=1}